# How to generate a .pdf file by keeping the Bootstrap 4 layout using C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4, pdf-generation, dinktopdf

I'm looking for a solution, in C# Asp.net, allowing me to generate a .pdf file of detailed statistics (of a Partialview I created) while keeping the layout of Bootstrap as well and my personal CSS too. I tried to use Dinktopdf but apparently this library does not support Bootstrap 4 flexboxes and I end up with a totally distorted statistics table

---

I expect this kind of result
[image: 1]

But the actual output is
[image: 2]

---

As you can see, the right column content seems to be out of document.
This is true that there is no wacky CSS for this document but I would like to reuse it on another document with more CSS styles.

If any of you would have a solution to this problem or would have another bookstore (instead of DinkToPdf) to suggest me.

Comment: I think it's a difficult task. You should use HTML tables to keep the layout consistent on PDF document.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this recently and found that the Bootstrap grid system worked well for this type of layout. here is what i used to get a split 2 column layout.

```
<div class='col-xs-6'>
    "add content here"
</div>
<div class='col-xs-6'>
</div>
    "add content here"
<div class='clearfix'></div>
```

the "clear fix" just ensures the next column div you add goes back to first column.

i also found that the HTML parsing of DinkToPDF is not great, make sure there are no extra spaces next <,>,= seems to confuse it.

Comment: What a stupid way. I've no idea why wkhtmltopdf does't like media queries. Thanks for the answer though.